# Nginx custom error page in protobuf content type

Tags: nginx, protocol-buffers, proto

Do you know is it possible to response with custom **protobuf messages** and content types during i.e 401/5XX errors from Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way to do it; lets say you have a proto file which has an error message inside i.e. under */etc/nginx/error.proto*, you can get your proto error message on 401 errors like this;

```
 error_page 401 /error.proto;

 location /error.proto {
     root /etc/nginx;
 }
```

You can also set content types to octet stream or your custom mime type